# COUNT, LIKE and EQUAL MySQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, select

How do I combined COUNT, LIKE and "EQUAL" in MySQL with PHP? I have the following query, is my "thinking" right. Or am I doing totaly wrong?

```
$query = 'SELECT COUNT(string) 
        AS 
        nums, string, post_number, city, other 
        FROM 
        tld 
        WHERE 
        (string LIKE "%'.$searchQuery.'%" 
        OR 
        post_number LIKE "%'.$searchQuery.'%" 
        OR 
        city LIKE "%'.$searchQuery.'%" 
        OR 
        other LIKE "%'.$searchQuery.'%" 
        AND 
        city = '.$filterId.'
        GROUP BY 
        string 
        ORDER BY 
        string ASC';
```

Comment: Combining a LIKE and a `=` on the same field doesn't make sense. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Did you get an error or just the result is wrong?

Comment: I am guessing that you need a closing ) just before `AND city =`

Comment: you have `(1 or 2 or 3 or 4 and 5)` , make it like `(1 or 2 or 3 or 4) and 5` if that is the desired condition

Comment: Add a closing parenthesis ')' before AND city as mishu said.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$query = 'SELECT COUNT(string) AS nums, string, post_number, city, other 
        FROM 
        tld 
        WHERE 
        (string LIKE "%'.$searchQuery.'%" 
        OR 
        post_number LIKE "%'.$searchQuery.'%" 
        OR 
        other LIKE "%'.$searchQuery.'%")
        AND
        (city LIKE "%'.$searchQuery.'%"
        OR
        city = '.$filterId.')
        GROUP BY 
        string 
        ORDER BY 
        string ASC';
```